# How to disable anonymous execution of a postgrest query

Tags: postgresql, rest, postgrest

Postgrest is rest API for postgreeSQL database.
I am using postgrest v9.0.0
with the following config:

```
db-uri = "postgres://remote_worker:1HyiYai@localhost:5432/myDb"
db-schema = "public"
db-anon-role = "remote_worker"
jwt-secret = "1HyiYaiMTAAJ1pluZnBtAMnTUH19E3gg"
db-pool = 10
db-pool-timeout = 10
server-host = "!4"
server-port = 3000
```

I assumed that if I enter the **jwt-secret** parameter in the config, it will automatically lead to the fact that only jwt authorization will work.

However, I can make a request without authorization
even just typing in the browser-> http://localhost:3000/myTable ?Id=eq.2.
or in the command line-> curl http://localhost:3000/Kits

At the same time when I make a request with
the authorization parameter for example curl http://localhost:3000/Kits -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyb2xlIjoicmVtb3RlX3dvcmtlciJ9.wAzG0zeHPYBflP4PhipUh0W8pvPLCbOQ2M4NFNTOSgc "
then the request passes only if the token is correct.

How can I disable anonymous execution of a request?

Answer (score 4):

When you didn't use a jwt token the role used is always the db-anon-role.
So depending on you database settings, this role can have a read access to the schema and display the response for the query.

If you want to have only authorized user you need to create a new user on your DB, remove the right on the schema for db-anon user and let only the new user with the usage on the schema.

the following postgres setting should work:

```
create role web_anon nologin;
create role authenticator
grant web_anon to authenticator;

create role rest_api nologin;
grant rest_api to authenticator;

create database "mydb" with owner rest_api
```

postgrest conf:

```
db-uri = "postgres://authenticator:omni123@localhost:5432/mydb"
db-schema = "public"
db-anon-role = "web_anon"
```

The default user web_anon don't have access to mybd all request with the token should work if you add the "role" rest_api in the jwt token as described in the documentation on postgrest https://postgrest.org/en/stable/tutorials/tut1.html#tut1

Comment: Thank you.
There is a little subtlety here.
The web_anon role does not need to be created.
You can write in the config:db-anon-role = "fake"
And everything will work.